# Does Ruby have an equivalent to maven2 resource filtering?

Tags: ruby, maven-2, vagrantfile, resource-files

Does ruby have an equivalent to Maven2's resource filtering?  In Maven2 it basically recursively goes though all the files of a specified name filter in a directory and takes the contents of search strings specified in `build.properties` and replaces the values searched for in the specified files.

I was wondering if Ruby has an equivalent functionality.

Comment: Not really, although a rake task to do it would be trivial. Whether or not it's a good idea depends on what you're actually trying to do, and why.

Comment: I'm trying to fill in values in files during the provisioning of a Vagrant VM.

Comment: Fill in values for what specifically? A vagrant file?

Comment: A bunch of config files that will be copied into the VM.  IP addresses that sort of thing.  I mean it would be nice if I could specify it in the Vagrantfile that way too.